# disable dragging in specific element (Item) in “Owl carousel” - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, draggable, carousel

I use "OWL Carousel" jQuery plugin (http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) for in my small project.

I create small script that draggable via this plugin. now i want to disable dragging in specific element (Item)... but i don't know how to do that.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="carousel">

    <div class="part">
        <div class="item">Item-1.1</div>
        <div class="item">Item-1.2 NOT Draggble</div>
        <div class="item">Item-1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="part">
        <div class="item">Item-2.1</div>
        <div class="item">Item-2.2 NOT Draggble</div>
        <div class="item">Item-2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="part">
        <div class="item">Item-3.1</div>
        <div class="item">Item-3.2 NOT Draggble<div>
        <div class="item">Item-3.3</div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.wrap {
    width: 990px;
    min-height: 360px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
div.item {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 324px;
    margin: 1px;
    min-height: 360px; 

}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#carousel").owlCarousel({
        singleItem: true,
    startPosition : -1,
    autoPlayDirection : "rtl",

    });

});
```

I know I should use to **mouseDrag** (http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing) in a **callback function** , but i don't now how ... :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem and just figured it out:

Add a class to the items you want to disable (i.e. "disable-owl-swipe") and stop event propagation on touchstart and mousedown, so the parents (the owl carousel wrappers) don't receive the event and therefore don't swipe.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="carousel">

    <div class="part">
        <div class="item">Item-1.1</div>
        <div class="item disable-owl-swipe">Item-1.2 NOT Draggble</div>
        <div class="item">Item-1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="part">
        <div class="item">Item-2.1</div>
        <div class="item disable-owl-swipe">Item-2.2 NOT Draggble</div>
        <div class="item">Item-2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="part">
        <div class="item">Item-3.1</div>
        <div class="item disable-owl-swipe">Item-3.2 NOT Draggble<div>
        <div class="item">Item-3.3</div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".disable-owl-swipe").on("touchstart mousedown", function(e) {
    // Prevent carousel swipe
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is amazing, used it for just an element, a selectbox that sometimes means you dragged while not moving accurately. This works like a charm with the owlcarousel beta 2

Comment: This worked perfectly for me using the Owl Carousel 2 beta, Thanks!

Comment: For crying out loud! It's amazing how you can get such perfect answers on Stackoverflow! Thx!

Answer (score 1):

**I have the solution!**
Just add the elements you want to exclude in "*NDElement*"

```
$( NDElement ).mousedown(function() {
        $(".owl-wrapper").attr("class","dontdragg"); 
});
$( document ).mouseup(function() {
        $(".dontdragg").attr("class","owl-wrapper"); 
});
```