# How to make a div not draggable inside a draggable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

So, I have a plugin that's called Owl-Carousel for sliding.

It slides automatically, but you can manually slide it too, by dragging the slides.

So I need to place some divs inside the slides; you can't drag the slide if you start the dragging from that div. It will scroll with the rest, but it's a clickable div, so I don't want people trying to click it and scrolling it whithout meaning to.

Here's a little example:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <figure>
        <div class="foo">Content...</div>
        <img src="blablabla.jpg">
    </figure>
</div>
```

So, I want the `foo` div to scroll with the rest, I just don't want be able to scroll the carousel by clicking on it and dragging, but i still want to be able to scroll by clicking anywhere else and dragging.

Is there a workaround for this?

In css there is the `pointer-events: none`, but the div needs to be clickable.

It can be in HTML, CSS, JavaScript(jQuery or "vanilla"), or it can be some option in Owl-Carousel too.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I'll try to rewrite the question to make it more understandable.

Comment: I did not rewrite it, but I added an example.

Answer (score -3):

Someone had a similar problem:

[disable dragging in specific element (Item) in “Owl carousel” - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909399/disable-dragging-in-specific-element-item-in-owl-carousel-jquery)

Maybe this will help.

Comment: You shouldn't add a new "answer" to mark question as duplication. You can flag post as duplication when you get 15 reputation points.